# Create multiple variables by id using the same data set in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2002", "2000", "2002", "2007"), id = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "Z", "Z"), product = c("apple",                                                                                                                                          "orange", "orange", "orange", "cake", "cake", "bacon"), market = c("CHN", "USA", "USA", "USA", "SPA", "CHL", "CHL"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

I want to create the following variables by id:

1. **years_PM** = number of years in this product and market (including year t-1)
2. **value_PM** = total value in this product and market (including year t-1)
3. **years_OPM** = number of years OTHER PRODUCTS in OTHER MARKETS (including year t-1)
4. **years_SP_OM** = number of years SAME PRODUCT in OTHER MARKETS (including year t-1)
5. **history** = takes value 1 if a given id has an history (including year t-1)
6. **year_id** = number of years of same id (including year t-1)
7. **year_id_consecutive** = number of years of same id. If there are more than 2 consecutive years without observing the same id, then it will assign a 0 (including year t-1) - e.g. the count will start from 0 (as a new observation).
8. **n_id_PM** = number of id's (different than the one observed) in this product and market (in year t-1)

Therefore, the new dataset will look like:

```
df_new <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2002", "2000", 
"2002", "2007"), id = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "Z", "Z"), product = c("apple", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "cake", "cake", "bacon"), market = c("CHN", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "SPA", "CHL", "CHL"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7), years_PM = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), value_PM = c(0, 
    0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0), years_OPM = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), years_SP_OM = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    history = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), year_id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 2), year_id_consecutive = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), n_id_PM = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I have used `summarise`, but it cuts the data. I dont want to merge multiple datasets afterwards. Moreover, `mutate` did not do the trick either.

Any idea how to use dplyr to create them more directly?

Comment: use ```mutate``` instead of ```summarise```

Comment: Can you include any code you've tried so far, even if it didn't fully work?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `summarize` (as has been said multiple times), it will (almost) always reduce your data.

Here's a shot, given various variables you've asked in the three iterations of this question.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(year = as.integer(year)) %>%
  group_by(product, market) %>%
  mutate(
    FPFM = +(year == min(year)),
    years_PM = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(year[year < y])),
    value_PM = sapply(year, function(y) sum(value[year < y])),
    n_id_PM = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(id[year < y]))
  ) %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(
    FP = +(year == min(year)),
    years_P = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(unique(year[year < y]))),
    value_P = sapply(year, function(y) sum(value[year < y])),
    n_id_P = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(id[year < y]))
  ) %>%
  group_by(market) %>%
  mutate(
    FM = +(year == min(year)),
    years_M = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(unique(year[year < y]))),
    value_M = sapply(year, function(y) sum(value[year < y])),
    n_id_M = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(id[year < y]))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    years_OPM   = mapply(function(y, p, m) n_distinct(year[year < y & product != p & market != m]),
                         year, product, market),
    years_SP_OM = mapply(function(y, p, m) n_distinct(year[year < y & product == p & market != m]),
                         year, product, market),
    years_OP_SM = mapply(function(y, p, m) n_distinct(year[year < y & product != p & market == m]),
                         year, product, market)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    history = +(lengths(sapply(year, function(y) year[year < y])) > 0),
    year_id = sapply(year, function(y) n_distinct(year[year < y])),
    year_id_consecutive = sapply(year, function(y) {
      years <- year[year < y]
      if (length(years)) {
        +(length(setdiff(seq(min(years), max(years)), years)) < 2)
      } else 0L
    })
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 × 23
#    year id    product market value  FPFM years_PM value_PM n_id_PM    FP years_P value_P n_id_P    FM years_M value_M n_id_M years_OPM years_SP_OM years_OP_SM history year_id year_id_consecutive
#   <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <int>    <int>    <dbl>   <int> <int>   <int>   <dbl>  <int> <int>   <int>   <dbl>  <int>     <int>       <int>       <int>   <int>   <int>               <int>
# 1  2000 X     apple   CHN        1     1        0        0       0     1       0       0      0     1       0       0      0         0           0           0       0       0                   0
# 2  2000 X     orange  USA        2     1        0        0       0     1       0       0      0     1       0       0      0         0           0           0       0       0                   0
# 3  2000 X     orange  USA        3     1        0        0       0     1       0       0      0     1       0       0      0         0           0           0       0       0                   0
# 4  2002 X     orange  USA        4     0        1        5       1     0       1       5      1     0       1       5      1         1           0           0       1       1                   1
# 5  2000 Z     cake    SPA        5     1        0        0       0     1       0       0      0     1       0       0      0         0           0           0       0       0                   0
# 6  2002 Z     cake    CHL        6     1        0        0       0     0       1       5      1     1       0       0      0         1           1           0       1       1                   1
# 7  2007 Z     bacon   CHL        7     1        0        0       0     1       0       0      0     0       1       6      1         2           0           1       1       2                   1
```

Some of the values are different from yours, but I think it's likely due to either errors in your expected output or misunderstanding/miscommunication of each column's intent.

The pattern should be clear for each: `group_by` the relevant variables, and as necessary iterate over `year` or some other variable (to limit to previous years) and count/sum/whatever.

I took the liberty of fixing `year` to be an integer.

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans . It is an amazing code. However, the output is not the expected. 1) Take as an example value_PM. The fourth element is orange-USA (2002). This combination appeared twice for the same id in the year 2000, with values 2+3. Therefore, it should be 5 instead of 2. Correct me if I am wrong, but your code is taking the first observation (2)? Also, 2) year_OPM should be (0,0,0,1,0,0,1) instead of (0,0,0,1,0,1,2). Moreover, 3) year_id_consecutive should be 0 in the last element given that this id did not show up two years before. 4)n_id_PM. Could help to solve these issues?

Comment: Update1: 4) year_OPM has been solved grouping by (id) before

Comment: Update2: value_PM now works. The error was driven because your code did not group by id

Comment: Update3: n_id_PM has been solved using mapply instead of sapply: `mapply(function(y, ident) n_distinct(id[year == y-1 & id != ident]),
                     year, id)`

Comment: For your first comment, you say that orange-usa-2002 appears twice, *"with values 2+3, therefore it should be 5 instead of 2"*. In my answer, it shows "5" not "2", so I don't understand you correcting me. For your `years_OPM` comment, `filter(quux, product!='bacon', market!='CHL', year<2007)` for instance returns 5 rows with 2 distinct years, so the value of `years_OPM` in row 7 should be 2, I don't understand how you can derive 1 from that. I suggest you go through each of your `0,0,0,1,0,0,1` for `years_OPM` and count each individual value, and justify your claim with details.

Comment: Regarding years_OPM: Before year t, for a given id, there are no observations with a different product AND market when it takes value 0. The same intuition applies when you have a 1 or another positive number. The only variable I can't modify from your code is `year_id_consecutive`. It doesnt start the "count" when an id is not showing up in the last two years. Do you have an intuition for doing so?

Comment: I must have missed the *"number of years OTHER PRODUCTS in OTHER MARKETS (including year t-1)"*. Add it to the `id`-grouping. Are you familiar with grouping calculations and the differences between `mutate` and `summarize`?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have modified them all. The only one I am not able to modify is `year_id_consecutive`. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: Yeah, that field was a problem for me to visualize and work through ... can't really resolve it now, but I suggest you look at the current code, add `browser()` (inside the `sapply` and `c`ontinue until you see `id` as `"Z"` and `y` as 2002 or 2007) and then work through the logic. I think it is likely an examination of the length after `setdiff(..)` or similar, but obviously it is not quite what you intended. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. If I understood correctly browser() inspects the error. However, there is no error but the calculations is not performing as expected (but its technically correct), isn't it?

Comment: No, `browser()` does not inspect the error, it will (from `?browser`): *"Interrupt the execution of an expression and allow the inspection of the environment where 'browser' was called from."* In other words, it allows you to troubleshoot what things look like (variables) interactively in the environment/namespace where you place `browser()`. In this case, it is intended to help you work through the logic yourself in the best place possible. While it can be used to find and work through errors, it can be used for many things. Welcome to [debugging in R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html).

Comment: Sorry @r2evans, It is not fully clear how to introduce and use browser().

Comment: Read the "debugging" link. Practice it. Then read it again. Debugging with breakpoints (such as with `browser()`) is not always easy, and it is not something I can easily say more about. I think `browser()` is by far the easiest of R's interactive debugging methods, and once you understand what it's giving you then it pays a lot of dividends. Good luck!